# php code for geeting paramenter and image from the post request

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c

can any one guide me how to get parameter specially image from the given post request.

```
--0xKhTmLbOuNdArY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="source"

lighttable
--0xKhTmLbOuNdArY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="title"

Google (The top search engine).
--0xKhTmLbOuNdArY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="isbn"

9780077282073
--0xKhTmLbOuNdArY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="price"

5
--0xKhTmLbOuNdArY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="condition"

Execlent
--0xKhTmLbOuNdArY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="media"

Content-Type: image/jpg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

ÿØÿà
```

NoTE:: ÿØÿà is the image in that request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look for $_POST and $_FILES in the PHP documentation.  For example: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

When posting logs like this, please try to include the entire HTTP request.  It should start with "POST /url/whatever HTTP/1.1" and include some headers.  The part you quoted is part of a multipart/mixed block, but it's hard to see if the rest of your request is correct or not.